# Why npm doesn't see quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, npm-install, quasar-framework

I installed quasar with a command: 
npm install -g @quasar/cli

Then I tried to create an app folder already with quasar:
quasar create callapp

The console is run in Visual Studio Code (last version), with administrator rights. I have tried reinstalling npm. 
npm version - 6.9.0
node version - v11.13.0

Installing quasar:

```
PS C:\Users\Daniels> npm install -g @quasar/cli
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Daniels\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar.cmd as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Daniels\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@quasar\cli
npm WARN rm not removing C:\Users\Daniels\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar as it wasn't installed by C:\Users\Daniels\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@quasar\cli
C:\Users\Daniels\AppData\Roaming\npm\quasar -> C:\Users\Daniels\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@quasar\cli\bin\quasar
+ @quasar/cli@1.0.0
updated 1 package in 14.635s
```

Creating app:

```
PS C:\Users\Daniels> quasar create callapp
quasar : Die Benennung "quasar" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die 
Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ quasar create callapp
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (quasar:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So it says that "quasar wasn't found as a name of Cmdlet or function or script of the programm. Please check the path and try again".

I expect that npm just finds quasar cli and I can work with it...

Answer (score 10):

If you installed only the npm like:

```
npm i -g quasar
```

you need also install the quasar cli:

```
npm install -g @quasar/cli
```

For more info here: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/installation

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message when I want to use quasar testing. In my case npx was the solution

npx quasar ...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32514212)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `yarn`, run this command to set the path:

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

Then, you can use `quasar`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with deleting node.js, deleting npm, restart of the system, installing another version of node.js (LTS Stable version), installing npm again.

Answer (score 1):

*Windows O/S*
make sure the "npm" data is part of %path%.
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users<your-id>\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 1):

in windows make sure to check your environment variables.
In my case with windows 8.1 environment i have to add manually to PATH

[Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP4fU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ps as a command prompt, you should restart ps to use the commands when you add a new package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:-

- Install node.js (V16 worked for me)
- Install Quasar npm install -g @quasar/cli
- make sure you access global installed npm packages by adding a path entry in your system variables i.e(C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm)